# Spring Integration Null correlation not allowed. Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting the error `Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?

This forum thread seemed to resolve it with something like the below, however that approach Is not working for me, http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/102054-aggregator-correlation-strategy-failing.

My understanding is that the inbound-streaming-channel-adapter puts FILE_NAME as a header value, and I'd like to join on that.

```
    <int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="true" id="ftpListener" channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="/export/home/udyj"
    filename-pattern="test1.txt">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="5000"
        max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

<int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="true" id="ftpListener2" channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="/export/home/udyj"
    filename-pattern="test2.txt">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="5000"
        max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

<bean id="correlationStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg value="FILE_NAME.substring(0,3)" />
</bean>
<integration:aggregator id="nuggetAggregator"
    input-channel="ftpChannel" output-channel="sendMQDistributionChannel"
    correlation-strategy="correlationStrategy">
</integration:aggregator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look, you say `HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy`, what definitely expect a header name to get. but at the same you specify the header name as a `FILE_NAME.substring(0,3)` which looks more like an expression. And you get null because there is really no such a header.

If you want to evaluate an expression, consider to use `ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy` instead:

```
<bean id="correlationStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.integration.aggregator.ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg value="headers.file_name.substring(0,3)" />
</bean>
```